# Error: while npm install command -> zsh: parse error near `\n'

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, npm-install, nrwl-nx

getting this error while running the install command  zsh: parse error near `\n'

Error - > zsh: parse error near `\n'

Trying to install

command -> npm i -g nx@<@nrwl/workspace 13.1.4>

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have < and > characters in the string that need to be escaped.
The message is generic, but the meaning is the same.
This said, I am not sure you should about the the line if you should not replace the content of <> by something custom to you